# How should I attach a wooden frame to legs?

Tags: fence, frame

Amazingly simple question that I can't seem to use google to find me the correct answer.

I need to build a rectangular frame built from fence posts that is also supported by 3x3 6ft fence posts. I know how to build the rectangle, but, what do I need to securely attach the frame to the posts?

==Edit==

The frame takes a little imagination.
I need to create a roll off roof section on a shed, so I want to frame the inside of the shed then extend back away from it 6ft.

Top down it would look like a digital figure of 8 with half of the 8 within the shed.

On top of the figure of 8 will be the roof on rails and wheels, so it needs to be a bit stronger than nails (I think)

In the picture you can see the near side frame structure, the cross beam will go inside the shed at the same height as the top of the wall and there will be another 6 ft beam attached there and running out to the upright nearest to me. But there will obviously be beams running at 90 degrees to this also and the same on the far side. I appreciate there will need to be some support battons running at 45 degrees from the uprights to the cross beams.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'frame'? Is it holding something? Are there fence posts on both sides? My gut reaction is: use nails or screws but we need more info, I think. A diagram or photo would be great.

Comment: Yeah thought my description might be a bit rubbish. I'll amend the question.

Comment: Took me reading a couple times, but if I'm right, we'd need more information, and I don't know that 3x3's are going to be adequate weight support. How is the "shed" built? How big is it? How big of a "sliding" roof do you need? What size wood is used for the wall-framing and roof framing? Are there trusses or just angled beams covered by particle board/shingles? Is it fastened to any sort of foundation? A picture might be useful, or a diagram.

Comment: The description helps but...well, this sounds pretty complex. Any chance we can see a sketch?

Comment: Lag bolts? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Even after your edit I can't picture what you're building or what the question is.

Comment: Hehe I have a photo to try and explain things better :)

Comment: Are the 4, what looks like maybe 5 or 6 ft tall, panels that are loosely fitted together supposed to be the shed? If not, a picture of the shed and the 3x3s (with some dimensions) are what I'd like to see. Maybe "shed" was just the wrong word? What is the large gray pole sticking up the middle. Maybe we should just start with, what are you trying to do in general?